# How to allow user to change focus of control after validate event using Devexpress Validation in WPF using C#?

Tags: c#, validation, xaml, devexpress

I have two `Radio Buttons` with options 'New' & 'Existing'. I have a Validate event for `Devexpress TextEdit` if `TextEdit` is empty and shows error icon in `TextEdit`. 
*Scenario:* When i Select 'New' `Radio button` and leave TextEdit Empty and click on 'Save' then it shows Error icon, this works fine. ***But, When i try to switch to 'Existing' `Radion button` then it do not allow me to switch/change the option instead it stuck to 'New' option due to validation. But, i want to allow the user to change option of Radio button.***

Xaml:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="rbNew" Content="New Mapping" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="Mappings" GotFocus="rbNew_GotFocus"/>
                    <dxe:TextEdit x:Name="txtMappingName" Grid.Column="1" Height="23" Margin="0,31,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxLength="100" Grid.RowSpan="2" GotFocus="txtMappingName_GotFocus" Validate="txtMappingName_Validate" />
                    <RadioButton  x:Name="rbExisting" Content="Existing Mapping" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" GroupName="Mappings"/>
```

xaml.cs

```
  private void txtMappingName_Validate(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.ValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((bool)rbNew.IsChecked && string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value as string))
            {
                e.IsValid = false;
                e.ErrorContent = "Required";
                e.ErrorType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider.ErrorType.Warning;
            }
        }
```

Help Appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking the property `InvalidValueBehavior` whether it is `AllowLeaveEditor`.
It should look like this:

```
<dxe:TextEdit x:Name="txtMappingName" Grid.Column="1" Height="23" Margin="0,31,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxLength="100" Grid.RowSpan="2" GotFocus="txtMappingName_GotFocus" Validate="txtMappingName_Validate" InvalidValueBehavior="AllowLeaveEditor"/>
```

Do let me know if this works.

Thanks.

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE Glad to be of help :)